# Выборка последних десяти записей в Mysql

Tags: mysql

Как в Mysql выбрать последние 10 записей? Думал сделать так `(mysql_insert_id() - 10)`, однако в этом промежутке могут быть уже удаленные ранее записи, и 10 последних записей не получится. Помогите,плз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

запрос

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

.....

Comment: Как все просто, спасибо. Иногда нужно включать мозг))